# How can i apply jquery function on a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to apply slimScroll function on 2 different divs. only one div is active at one time.
So, i am using a variable to get current tab name. When user clicks Reviews, slimscroll shall apply on #reviews and if gallery is clicked, it should switch to gallery.

html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
   <li class="active"><a href="#reviews" data-toggle="tab">Reviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#gallery" data-toggle="tab">Gallery</a></li>
</ul><!-- tabs -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="reviews">
        reviews
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="gallery">
        gallery
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-pills li a').on('click',function(){
        var current = ($(this).text());
        alert(current);
    });
    $('article').slimScroll({
        position: 'right',
        height: '370px',
        railVisible: true,
        alwaysVisible: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-pills li a').on('click',function(){
        var current = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        //$('div.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
        //$('div#'+current).addClass('active');
        alert(current);

        $('#'+current).slimScroll({
        position: 'right',
        height: '370px',
        railVisible: true,
        alwaysVisible: true
    });
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav-pills li a').on('click',function(){
            var current = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
            $(this).closest('ul').find('div.tab-content').find('div.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
            $('div#'+current).addClass('active');
            alert(current);

            $('#'+current).slimScroll({
            position: 'right',
            height: '370px',
            railVisible: true,
            alwaysVisible: true
        });
```

Comment: ok, first one worked but it shows both sections at the same time i.e. gallery and reviews at same time.

Comment: you want to hide the other div or only want to apply slimscroll?

Comment: Gallery and reviews are two tabs. When review is active gallery shouldn't be there and vice versa.

Comment: I am using bootstrap so .active class switches using bootstrap.js

Comment: see the edited one you need to remove active class from all li and the add active class to cureent li clicked

Comment: Thnx for ur help, it has solved a part of the problem, I'll deal with the rest.

Comment: welcome and glad that my code helped you in some way..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav-pills li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parents('li').siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $($(this).find('a').attr('href')).unbind('slimscroll');
    });

    $($(this).attr('href')).slimScroll({
        position: 'right',
        height: '370px',
        railVisible: true,
        alwaysVisible: true
    });
});
```